# How to reload jQuery multiselect in a drowdown list when the selection of another dropdown changes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have tried some of the solutions proposed in this forum but they did not work for so I think I am missing something somewhere.

I am using Patrick Springstubbe jQuery multiselect on two dropdown lists(ProductCategories and Products).

I want the list of products to change depending on what's selected in the ProductCategories multiselect.

The code I am using for that is as follows:-

```js
 $("#ProductCategory").change(

  function () {

  $("#leftlist").empty();

  $("#ProductCategory").children("option:selected").each(function () {

   ResetLeftList(($(this).val()));  

  });
  
  $('#leftlist').multiselect( 'reload' );

 });
```

```js
function ResetLeftList(ProductCategoryID) {

  //Get list of food for categoryID

  $.ajax

  ({

    url: "http://example.com/index.php?id=18",
    data: {
      PostProductCategoryID: ProductCategoryID
    },
    method: "post",
    success: function(result) {

      var trimmedresult = result.substring(3, result.length - 4);
      var newOptions = trimmedresult.split(";");

      for (i = 0; i < newOptions.length; i++) {

        var option = newOptions[i].split(",");

        $("#leftlist").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", option[0]).text(option[1]));

      }

    }

  });


}
```

Problem:- The product multiselect don't update

Observation:- Using developer tool on the web browser I can see that the list of options in the product list is changing as expected.
If I remove `$("#leftlist").empty();` the product multilist updates based on the previously selected options from the category list.
It appears that `$('#leftlist').multiselect( 'reload' )` is firing before the option changes in the product list.

Comment: please try consolidating both snippets into a working one, some sample html included, so we're able to reproduce the scenario and come up with a possible solution

Comment: To reproduce the scenario you may go you the url of my developing site http://fansip.wowislandcharter.com/ 

For those checking this post at a later date please note that this link will be changed once the development is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right "$('#leftlist').multiselect( 'reload' ) is firing before the option changes in the product list.".

> [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) performs an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

which means that code will continue executing after $.ajax() is called.

You can use the [jqXHR Object returned by $.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) and place the reload code in a callback that will be executed when the request is finished.

### Return the jqXHR Object:

```
function ResetLeftList(ProductCategoryID) {
    return $.ajax
```

### Wait for all ajax to finish

```
 var requests = new Array();

 $("#ProductCategory").children("option:selected").each(function () {

     requests.push(ResetLeftList(($(this).val())));     

 });

 $.when.apply($, requests).done(function( x ) {
     $('#leftlist').multiselect( 'reload' );
 });
```

Comment: https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxcombobox/index.htm#demos/jqxcombobox/cascadingcombobox.htm this is also another best option .You can try if you require.